# jQuery collapsible

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an unordered list where each `<li>` contains another unordered list. The list item that I want to trigger the slide down of the submenu has class `mobile-collapse` and the submenu has class `mobile-drop-menu`. Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".mobile-drop-menu").hide();
$(".mobile-collapse").click(function() { 
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
});


</script>
```

but when I test it out and click the `mobile-collapse <li>` it disappears. Here is a link to test it out. You will have to drag your window size to pretty small for the unordered list to appear. https://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/boot/student.shtml#

Could someone help me fix this issue or find a better way to achieve this goal? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your list are in this form

```
<li class="mobile-collapse"><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="mobile-drop-menu">
            <li><a href="#">International Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teacher Employment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diverse Populations</a></li>
        </ul>
```

so `<a href="#">Services</a>` is also the children of `li` with class `mobile-collapse`
so doing `$(this).children().slideToggle();` will **hide/show** all the children of `li` with `mobile-collapse` class which are :

```
<a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="mobile-drop-menu">
            <li><a href="#">International Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teacher Employment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diverse Populations</a></li>
        </ul>
```

so, change your function to this : you need to search the list using `find()` escaping `<a>`

```
    $(function() {
    $(".mobile-drop-menu").hide();
    $(".mobile-collapse").click(function() { 
        $(this).find('.mobile-drop-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @MattAltepeter upvoted you as well :) you actually taught me well about responsive web design :)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery slideToggle simply use
"`display:block`" or "`display:none`" to show or hide element.

```
$(this).children().slideToggle();
```

This will operate on all the child element of "**mobile-collapse**" class which includes the link. So we need to filter out the link element.

You can change the line: 

`$(this).children().slideToggle();`
**to**
`$(this).children(".mobile-drop-menu").slideToggle();`

Hope this will work.